# plugin Indoor positioning system on Flutter?

Tags: flutter, indoor-positioning-system

i want build app with indoor positioning system, are there plugin or reference in flutter ?

i was search on google, that's no clue for me to build this app.

it is possible use plugin location, because if you in a building, your location sometimes error, if not error your location is wrong. and i think using location.HIGH is can reduce batteries faster